# Is it possible that the subset of the set of axioms may be true in $\mathbb{N}$, but the whole set is not true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It seems for me like straightforward answer, but I still want to make sure I am on the right track.
Consider infinite set of axioms $\Gamma = \{ k > 1, k > 1+1, k>1+1+1, ....\}$.
Where k is a new constant which is clearly bigger than any natural number.
What I am trying to say is that each finite subset of $\Gamma$ is True withing $\mathbb{N}$, but the whole infinite $\Gamma$ is not True for $\mathbb{N}$.
E.g consider subset $S = \{ k > 1, k > 1+1, ..., k > n\}$. I am saying that $\mathbb{N} \vDash S$ because we can find an interpretation of $k$, such as $k + 1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure if I am saying the right thing. Is it correct to say 
$\mathbb{N} \vDash S$ just because we can find such natural number $k$ that makes all axioms true within $\mathbb{N}$?

I also think we cannot say that $\mathbb{N} \vDash \Gamma$ because in this case we cannot find interpretation of $k$ within $\mathbb{N}$ such that it satisfies all axioms of $\Gamma$ and therefore we need to have some new structure that is the same as $\mathbb{N}$ but has in addition constant k and its interpretation.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely on the right track. $\Bbb N$ is a model of any finite subset of your set of axioms $\Gamma$ but $\Bbb N$ is not a model of the whole set  $\Gamma$. The compactness theorem implies that $\Gamma$ (together with the usual axioms of arithmetic) has a model. That model will include a copy of $\Bbb N$ together with an interpretation of the transfinite constant $k$. It will also include many other transfinite elements to interpret terms such as $k+1$, $k - 2$, $2k$, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic for some more detail.

Comment: You said "The compactness theorem implies.." can you elaborate more on that? I checked wiki on compactness theorem but I did not understand much...

Comment: It's the compactness theorem for first-order logic described in the first paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem that I am referring to. What didn't you understand?

Comment: Compactness Theorem says that if $\Gamma$ is inconsistent then there is a subset of $\Gamma$ which is inconsistent. How this implies about model?

Comment: The compactness implies that if $\Gamma$ is inconsistent then there is a **finite** subset of $\Gamma$ that is inconcistent. However, it is usually stated (as it is on the wiki page that I cited ) as saying that if any finite subset of $\Gamma$ has a model, then $\Gamma$ has a model.